# Building a truth table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following sample table

```
User | Event 
=============
Bob    EventX
Steve  EventA
Bob    EventC
Jane   EventB
Jane   EventA
Bob    EventC
```

I want to build a truth table that just tells me if a particular User has fired a particular event

```
User | EventA | EventB | Event C | Event X
===============================================
Bob     False    False    True      True
Steve   True     False    False     False
Jane    True      True    False     False
```

Is there any way to this in SQL instead of having to write code to build this table?

thank you

Comment: Yes there is but can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT user, max(iif(event='EventA','True','False')) as 'EventA', .. 
FROM events
GROUP BY user;
```

Comment: change up max(if  to max(iif.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Pivot (MSSQL sample below.) .  You will have to specify each column in the Pivot FOR (..) list

```
DECLARE @Events AS TABLE
    (
    EventId     VARCHAR(20)
    ,UserName   VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT INTO @Events (EventId, UserName)  VALUES('EventA','BOB')
INSERT INTO @Events (EventId, UserName)  VALUES('EventA','STEVE')
INSERT INTO @Events (EventId, UserName)  VALUES('EventB','STEVE')
INSERT INTO @Events (EventId, UserName)  VALUES('EventB','STEVE')
INSERT INTO @Events (EventId, UserName)  VALUES('EventB','STEVE')


SELECT
      PivotedList.UserName 
     ,CASE WHEN PivotedList.EventA IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS EventA
     ,CASE WHEN PivotedList.EventB IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS EventB

FROM
    @Events AS Events

    PIVOT 
    (
    MAX(EventId)
    FOR EventId IN ([EventA],[EventB])

    ) AS PivotedList
```

RESULTS:

```
UserName    EventA  EventB
=================================
BOB         TRUE    FALSE
STEVE       TRUE    TRUE
```